# Same codebase for CPU and GPU

Tags: c, gpgpu

Does anybody have any experience in maintaining single codebase for both CPU and GPU? 
I want to create an application which when possible would use GPU for some long lasting calculations, but if a compatible GPU is not present on a target machine it would just use regular CPU version. It would be really helpfull if I could just write a portion of code using conditional compilation directives which would compile both to a CPU version and GPU version. Of course there will be some parts which are different for CPU and GPU, but I would like to keep the essense of the algorithm in one place. Is it at all possible?

Comment: You didn't specify an operating system but I would expect this to be operating-system specific.

Comment: It is unlikely that you would want to use the exact same code structure for both CPU and GPU, as it would not be optimal for both.

Comment: Sure this is possible an abstract sense. It requires some organization, but it's certainly doable. Have a look at [Thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) for example (which is now bundled with CUDA). It provides several back-ends for the actual computation.

Comment: I definitely need Windows, but I wouldn't mind if I could get both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Bart Thanks. Thrust looks very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) is a C-based language. OpenCL platforms exist that run on GPUs (from [NVidia](http://developer.nvidia.com/opencl) and [AMD](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/stream-technology/opencl/pages/opencl.aspx)) and CPUs (from [Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vcsource-tools-opencl-sdk/) and [AMD](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/stream-technology/opencl/pages/opencl.aspx)).

While it is possible to execute the same OpenCL code on both GPUs and CPUs, it really needs to be optimized for the target device.  Different code would need to be written for different GPUs and CPUs to gain the best performance.  However, a CPU OpenCL platform can function as a low-performance fallback for even GPU optimized code.

If you are happy writing conditional directives that execute depending on the target device (CPU or GPU) then that can help performance of OpenCL code on multiple devices.

Comment: As far as I know CUDA also uses a variant of C/C++ language. Also there's new Visual Studio 11 which is supposed to support both ATI and NVidia GPUs. So I think I'm not restricted to only OpenGL, or am I? Another point is that I agree to write some CPU/GPU specific code, I just don't want to keep two versions of the main logic of the algorithm.